# Can't able to select a specific list that I want in Selenium + C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, nunittestadapter

Actually, I wanted to select a specific list that I want inside a container. But I try to write with the code below but it is not reflecting:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

IWebElement mainMenu = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='requestItemSFHD-24']"));

actions.MoveToElement(mainMenu).Build().Perform();

actions.MoveToElement(mainMenu).Click();
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwwI6.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to do, actually? Can you describe use case?

Comment: Let say you have 5 values in a container. Do you wanted to select 3 or 4 values from the container?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov I wanted to select one of the request that contain inside the container to check whether it will redirect to the page that display the correct information or not

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan exactly what i want

Comment: Can you give more information with the DOM structure and screenshot. Try to insert the screenshot in the question itself rather than providing as a link.

Comment: I have attach a screenshot in my question.@AshokkumarGanesan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement mainMenu = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("requestItem-target"));
actions.MoveToElement(mainMenu).Build().Perform();
driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("requestItem-target")).ElementAt(1).Click();
```